# Local connection to a blocked port goes through

Tags: windows, logstash, windows-firewall, filebeat

I've been playing around with `filebeat` and `logstash`. I configured `filebeat` to send on port `5043` and `logstash` listening on that port.

I've blocked the outgoing `5043` port for local and remote connections using windows firewall but somehow, `filebeat` still gets through.

I've wondered, why is this? Is it because it was just sending locally and not really "outgoing"? (it didn't actually come out) but then again, it was supposed to block local connections as well. Can anyone shed some light on this? Many thanks.

Edit: Added screenshot
[Blocked port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Rz8.png)

Comment: I'm confused as to what Local port and Remote port mean. Does local port mean within the local network or the internal traffic?

Comment: @paaaaat: Just like a connection has an IP address at each end, it has a TCP port at each end.  "Local port" means the TCP port at the end of the connection that's on your computer, "Remote port" means the TCP port at the other end of the connection.  Usually only the server end of a connection has a *well-known port number*, the client will use what's known as an *ephemeral port number*, basically just letting the OS pick any available one.

Comment: What Ben said.  The firewall rule shown in the screenshot only applies to TCP traffic going from port 5043 on your machine to port 5043 on a remote machine.  Even if logstash were on another machine, that rule probably wouldn't apply, because although filebeat will be sending *to* port 5043, it probably won't be sending *from* port 5043.

Comment: I see. So if I block block the remote port 5043, it means that I'm blocking outgoing traffic GOING TO port 5043 of any destination. If I block the local port 5043, it means that I'm blocking traffic COMING FROM my own port 5043. Is that correct?

So then, why is it that since my logstash is listening on port 5043, the blocked remote port 5043 is not kicking in? Is it because both logstash and filebeat are running on the same machine and windows firewall isn't blocking any traffic?

Comment: For one thing, when you specify both a local port and a remote port, both ports must match for the rule to apply.  But yes, in this case, since both processes are running on the same machine, Windows Firewall has no effect, no matter how it is configured.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: But I've set it to block remote and local port 5043. Shouldn't it block traffic going from port 5043 and traffic going to port 5043 on any remote machine?

I get it. I should remove the block to the local port and set it to any port so that traffic going to port 5043 gets blocked, regardless of which port it comes from?

Comment: If you want to prevent applications on your machine from contacting port 5043 on remote machines, you need to set the "local port" option to "any port".  (It still won't affect traffic between processes on the same machine.)

Comment: I see. Thank you.